# Can you execute a task which requires elevation without reopening reopening win32 window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

Is it possible to execute a task which requires elevation(in my example, I have to edit the registry) without reopening the whole window?
So i have a CPL item which and of its pages has the option to edit my application´s settings(which are written into the registry). Is it possible to do it only when user clicks `apply` or `ok`? But without reopening the whole cpl window.

Comment: When applying the changes, launch another instance of your control panel item calling [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) (passing the *runas* verb). You can pass a command line telling that other process to apply changes, and not show a GUI at all. Once the changes are applied, exit the process.

Comment: Is my solution proper way to do it or there is a better way?

Comment: An alternative geeky way is to use the COM interface that's used internally by `ShellExecuteEx`. But that means having a COM server process running. Because the UAC "security" has process granularity.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You can define your own COM object to perform the task, and then use the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) to create that COM object in an elevated state. No need to access `ShellExecuteEx`'s internal COM object(s) directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `ShellExecuteEx`uses the COM Elevation Moniker. Sorry I don't have time to do everyone's research. Thanks for doing it. In an "answer" I'd have had to look it up though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alf's comment already says as much: no. Windows are tied to processes, and a process cannot be elevated after creation.

Of course, you can have a second child process which doesn't actually *show* anything, but just performs the requested task.

Or, you can define your own COM object to perform the requested task, and then use the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) to create that COM object in an elevated state when needed.